# How to get my send button centered and responsive according the form?

Tags: html, css

[image]Q1. When resizing, the text inside the submit button gets cut since the container seems to be smaller. How can I still show the text and resize the container accordingly?

Q2. How can I get the name input field the same size as the other input fields?
As you can see the width is not exactly the same. 
I tried everything, am clueless at this stage.

See website: http://demo.chilipress.com/epic3/

Comment: Set a `min-width` for your button?

Comment: @kei do you know how I can resolve Q2?

Answer (score 0):

Add `min-width` to css of `.sendButton`
e.g.

```
.sendButton {
    min-width: 100px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you also know how I can resolve Q2?
I could then give you points for your answer.

Comment: Q2 is not quite clear as to what you want and what you're getting. Maybe rephrase it?

Comment: I added an image and rephrased the question. 
Hope it is clear now.